# Calculate mean and std.dev from a lot of coordinates

Tags: statistics, coordinate-systems, standard-deviation

How do i calculate the mean coordinate and the standard deviation of a cloud of (x,y) coordinates. 
I know how to calculate the mean, but i am struggling with calculating the std. deviation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'center' of a data cloud is often taken as
the point $(\bar X, \bar Y).$ Similarly, you probably
want to find the standard deviations of X's and Y's 
separately.

If this does not answer your question, how about
telling us more about the specific problem.

Comment: Exactly as you say.. 
found the formula.. :)